# NSData contentsOfURL is not getting called when app is in background

Tags: ios, swift, image, url, download

Using swift 2.3

For downloading the image from web URL, I have written below function. It works fine when the app is running in the foreground.

But when the app is running in background contentsOfURL is not getting called and return invalid.

What is the correct method to do this ?

```
extension UIImage
{
    class func getImgFrmWebUrlFnc(WebUrlVar : String) -> UIImage?
    {
        let UrlVar = WebUrlVar + ".jpg"
        if let ImgDataVar = NSData(contentsOfURL: NSURL(string: UrlVar)!)
        {
            if let ResImgVar = UIImage(data:ImgDataVar)
            {
                print("Web Url Valid : ", UrlVar)
                return ResImgVar
            }
        }
        print("Web Url invalid : ", UrlVar)
        return nil
    }
}
```

Usage :

```
(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH,0))
{
     let imageVar = UIImage.getImgFrmWebUrlFnc("http://websitename/Webpath/nameImg.jpg")
}
```

When the app is in running in the foreground :

> Web Url Valid : http://websitename/Webpath/nameImg.jpg

When the app is in running in the background :

> Web Url invalid : http://websitename/Webpath/nameImg.jpg

Comment: 1. Why are you still using Swift 2? 2. Never use `NSData(contentsOfURL:)`. Use `NSURLSession` and create a data task.

Comment: +1 rmaddy..., specifically, you wanna use `https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsurlsessionconfiguration/1407496-backgroundsessionconfigurationwi?language=objc` when your app goes to background. [Here are more info from apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html)